# Excel: using 2 cells to collect data from a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

My Example is this:

```
(workbook name"Rev)
letter  weekly  bi-weekly monthly
a        100     200       400
b        110     250       500
c        111     300       600
d        112     350       700
e        113     400       800
```

on a different workbook I will enter in a letter and either weekly,bi-weekly, or monthly. i need excel to pull the # associated with that.
IE: cell 1 = B cell 2 = monthly cell 3 = 400<- but this is pulled automatically.

I would really like to avoid a macro if its possible.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished through a combination of the `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions. For example:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$6, MATCH($G$2, $A$1:$A$6, 0), MATCH($G$1, $A$1:$D$1, 0))
```

The `MATCH` function determines the target row and column, and the `INDEX` function looks up the cell in that row and column. The table range (`A1:D6`) and input cell addresses (`G1` and `G2`)can be customized to your needs.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Index/Match

=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$6,MATCH(Sheet2!B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6,0),MATCH(Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,0))

A1 to D6 on sheet1 is where the data is. On sheet2 enter "b" into cell B1 and "monthly" into cell B2.